# PHP function returning NULL instead of array

Tags: php, arrays

I call a function that does some recursion and is supposed to return an array.  In fact, a var_dump immediately before the return statement in the called function evinces the array; however, a var_dump of the results from the calling function reveals NULL instead of the array.

Here's the calling function.

```
<?php  

// configuration
require_once("../includes/config.php");
require_once("../includes/getParentNodes.php");  

$bottomNode = 17389;
$chain = [];
$chain[] = $bottomNode;
$results = getParentNodes($bottomNode,$chain);

var_dump($results); ?>
```

Here's the called function.

```
<?php

function getParentNodes($node, $results)
{
    $select = query("SELECT parent_id FROM classifications WHERE node_id = ?", $node);
    $parent = implode("",$select[0]);
    if (!empty($parent))
    {
        $results[] = $parent;
        getParentNodes($parent,$results);   
    }
    else
    {
        return $results;
    }
}
?>
```

If I place a var_dump immediately preceding the return call, I get the following.

```
Array
(
    [0] => 17389
    [1] => 17386
    [2] => 17334
    [3] => 16788
    [4] => 15157
    [5] => 10648
    [6] => 3962
    [7] => 665
    [8] => 39
    [9] => 1
)
```

However, the var_dump in the calling function produces a NULL.

I've read the manual and the related posts, but none shed light on this problem.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? > 5.3 I hope, which is probably your problem. The reason is that short array syntax wasn't a thing until PHP 5.4

Comment: change your value of `function getParentNodes($node, $results)` to rename this `$results` variable to another name, so stop name overlaps.

Comment: When you make the recursive called to `getParentNodes()` from within the function you discard the returned value so nothing gets passed back up the chain.

Comment: @ArtisitcPhoenix, i'm running version 5.6.8.

Comment: @Martin, good observation.  I actually changed those variables subsequent to the post to no effect.

Answer (score 4):

You're missing a `return` in the recursive case.

```
      $results[] = $parent;
      return getParentNodes($parent,$results);
```

Comment: wow do I feel silly.  You are correct.  I totally missed the other return call.  It works perfectly now. Many thanks Mark

Comment: Glad I could help.  If you could please accept the answer, that'd be great. :)

Answer (score 2):

There is a little error on the code:

```
function getParentNodes($node, $results)
{
    $select = query("SELECT parent_id FROM classifications WHERE node_id = ?", $node);
    $parent = implode("",$select[0]);
    if (!empty($parent))
    {
        $results[] = $parent;
        return getParentNodes($parent,$results); // <- modified
    }
    else
    {
        return $results;
    }
}
```